# Update the AdobeIllustrator file using C#

Tags: c#-4.0

I need to update the particular text in Adobe illustrator file(Ai) using .net.
Please give me the solution.

Regards
Munirathnam

Comment: Please give me some money. We're not here to do your work. What have you tried so far that isn't working? Have you searched anything?

Comment: I am not asking you to work for me. I am asking some suggestions and best ways in order to accomplish my work. This is a forum to look for best approaches and to get people feedbacks and suggestions to handle the work in proper way. I am asking only proper guidance and links not your effort.